# Nested field_value_factor on individual field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some document with mapping looks like following

```js
{  
   "documents":[  
      {  
         "author":"name1",
         "books":[  
            {  
               "title":"title1",
               "content":"content1",
               "rating":5
            },
            {  
               "title":"title2",
               "content":"content2",
               "rating":1
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "author":"name2",
         "books":[  
            {  
               "title":"title1",
               "content":"content1",
               "rating":3
            },
            {  
               "title":"title2",
               "content":"content2",
               "rating":3
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to return a list of authors whose book contents match certain keywords. But at the same time, I want the score on each documents.books.content is boosted by documents.books.rating, then combine these score together.

Anyway, I can do that with function score?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the function score is supposed to do. Take a look at this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about that. Because what I am hoping to is not just the entire score, but on the individual search field. For example, it will search for how relevant is the content of each book, then each relevance score on the content is boosted by the rating. Then combine the relevance of all these books to rank authors. In that case, if you think function_score would work, could you kindly show me an example? Thank you!